# SQLite3 DateTime comparison in linux

Tags: datetime, sqlite

As per seen in image my first query return 5 rows but my second query does not return any rows.
It shoud be return 3 rows.

[image]

I also have tried with
Store my all datetime data in format of 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'

"SELECT billheaderid,billheadercode,billtotalitem,billtotalamount,createdby,createdon WHERE cretedon >= Datetime('2014-08-19 12:26:32')"

Answer (score 1):

Date values with "AM/PM" fields cannot be compared correctly with string comparisons
(`1` is larger than `0`).

You have to change all the values in the database to the correct format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`.
(And it is not necessary to call the `datetime` function.)

Answer (score 1):

Store your data in form of
'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'

And please care that '2014-08-19 03:45 PM' must be store as '2014-08-19 15:45:23' not as '2014-08-19 03:45:23'.

After that you don't need use datetime function. I am sure it'll work 100%.

Comment: Actually i have stored date as "2014-08-19 03:45:26" in place of "2014-08-19 15:45:26".